# How to use loop to find related object using Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: apex, custom-object, migration-tool, migration, job

I want to identify the bad/invalid records so that i can add in a separate SQL Table.
For example, we have an account object. And i want to find bad accounts. But i need to apply some filters on contact object. If conditions satisfy based on contact then i want to inserts those invalid account records in SQL Table.

I don't want to directly query from contact. I want to query using account but conditions should be used from contact.

Do you know what is the best way to perform loop in Pentaho? Check each record for contact , if all contact's condition satisfy then add Account id in table. If one of the contact record doesn't satisfy condition. The relevant account should not be added in SQL Table

For Example:

On Account "A" we have 10 contacts
if the email field is empty on all 10 contacts then add Account in SQL table(As bad data)
On two of contact object has email but 8 of them are blank then Account id shouldn't be added   in SQL table

How we can better do this scenario using Pentaho?
Any help matters

Thanks

Comment: You should check with Pentaho support and Pentaho community forums.

Comment: If Pentaho support is not providing any kind of support/Flow, then please create that Rollup Helper Logic in Salesforce. 
Identify those records in Salesforce, and Mark them as Bad Account Data.
Finally, whoever you will list of Accounts in API, you can identify them easily and insert them into SQL Table(As Bad Data).